# Should I not install software in Dockerfile as root?

Tags: docker, security, dockerfile

I read in [this blog](https://medium.com/@mccode/processes-in-containers-should-not-run-as-root-2feae3f0df3b#:%7E:text=Most%20containerized%20processes%20are%20application,easy%20method%20to%20limit%20access.) a great explanation about why you shouldn't run containers as root user, and instead create a user in the dockerfile, and use the `USER` keyword to switch to that user.

My question is that: Say I want to have a docker image with some software installed on it, in my case it's Xilinx Vivado, which is a development tool. Is that a bad practice to do all the installation steps as root and switch to the USER at the end of the Dockerfile? What are the considerations regarding this?

Answer (score 2):

For building images and installing the applications, you typically need to be root. Same as if you are on a Linux host and want to `apt-get install ...`. So leaving the `USER` step to the end of the Dockerfile is fairly standard. The issue is less often with building the image which is controlled. Rather it's later when you run the container and have external inputs/users that can cause that application inside that image to do bad things.